# how to get the row sorted with title letter in mysql

Tags: mysql

i've a table

```
 ---------
|   NAME  |
|---------|
|  arun   |
|  balu   |
|  sunny  |
|  binu   |
|  binoy  |
|  cinny  |
|  aiju   |
|  dolly  |
 ---------
```

i've wrote a query to get sorted list in mysql

```
SELECT name FROM students ORDER BY name ASC
```

and i got it all names sorted but i don't know how to get the output as shown below

```
 ---------
|   NAME  |
|---------|
|    A    |
|  aiju   |
|  arun   |
|    B    |
|  balu   |
|  binoy  |
|  binu   |
|    C    |
|  cinny  |
|    D    |
|  dolly  |
|    S    |
|  sunny  |
 ---------
```

can anyone please tell me how to get this output?

Comment: One ought to perform operations of this sort in the presentation layer of one's application, rather than in the database.

Comment: but does it possible to print this output using mysql query

Comment: It's possible, but you probably shouldn't do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform this in SQL, then you could use a `UNION ALL` query.  The first query will return the `name` and the second query will return the first letter of each name. Then you can `ORDER BY` the result:

```
select name
from yourtable
union all
select distinct upper(left(name, 1))
from yourtable
order by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be1316/4)

The result is:

```
|  NAME |
---------
|     A |
|  aiju |
|  arun |
|     B |
|  balu |
| binoy |
|  binu |
|     C |
| cinny |
|     D |
| dolly |
|     S |
| sunny |
```

Comment: Nice solution without using a table with ('A'), ('B'), ... in it.

Comment: @DMac that was the route I was going at first and then I realized it was not needed. :)